# Change Color Themes - How To Prevent the Site Goes Back to Default

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a default css file for my website and link into the master page.

```
<link href="~/Content/blue/mainCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" title="main" />
```

Then, I have Jquery code to change the color theme as below

```
   $(".greenSquare").on('click', function (e) {
        $('link[title="main"]').attr('href', '~/Content/green/mainCSS.css');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

The function works well, when the greenSquare is click, the site color is changed to green.  However, after another page is loaded, it goes back to the default color theme, unfortunately.

How to prevent the site goes back to the default color?
Thanks,

EDIT to get Storage involved

```
$(".greenSquare").on('click', function set_theme(theme) {
    $('link[title="main"]').attr('href', '~/Content/green/mainCSS.css');
});
if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {

    function set_theme(theme) {
        $('link[title="main"]').attr('href', '~/Content/green/mainCSS.css');
        if (supports_storage) {
            localStorage.theme = theme;
        }
        if (supports_storage) {
            var theme = localStorage.theme;
            if (theme) {
                set_theme(theme);
            }
        } else {


        }
    }
}
```

But somehow it doesn't work, yet.

Comment: You could store the selection in localStorage or a cookie.

Comment: "... I have a Jquery syntax..." Just to clarify: you don't have "a syntax." Syntax is the rules that define a grammar. What you have is a snippet of JavaScript that uses jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save the color information across page loads.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Cookie</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="" rel="stylesheet" title="main" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        // When the page loads, look for the cookie value.
         var currentColor = localStorage.getItem('my_bgcolor');   

        // If you find it
        if (currentColor === "green") {
            $('link[title="main"]').attr('href', 'green.css');
        }
        if (currentColor === "red") {
            $('link[title="main"]').attr('href', 'red.css');
        }
        if (currentColor === "") {
            $('link[title="main"]').attr('href', 'green.css');
        }

       $(".greenSquare").on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('link[title="main"]').attr('href', 'green.css');
            // Set the storage item to 'green'.
            localStorage.setItem('my_bgcolor', 'green');
        });
       $(".redSquare").on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('link[title="main"]').attr('href', 'red.css');
            // Set the storage item to 'red'.
            localStorage.setItem('my_bgcolor', 'red');      
        });

    });
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <a href="#" class="greenSquare" id="green">Click Me</a>
    <a href="#" class="redSquare" id="red">Click Me</a>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Medinasod!  It works, but I saw a little thing happen.  The default color is red, after I pick green, everything change to green. Another page loads, the red color shows up in 1 second and then green overwrites it.  How comes it happens like that?  Any idea.  Thanks

Comment: It's because the browser is reading the link tag's href attribute from the html before the JavaScript is executed. You could prevent that by making the default href value dynamic rather than hard coded. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much, Medinasod, It works well!  I just run into another issue that instead of having 1 style sheet link `<link href="" rel="stylesheet" title="main" />`, it needs to have another one `<link href="" rel="stylesheet" title="main1" />`.  Should I have 1 localStorage `var currentColor = localStorage.getItem('my_bgcolor');` or 2?  I made 1 localStorage, it doesn't work. `if (currentColor === "green") {
            $('link[title="main"]').attr('href', 'green.css'); $('link[title="main1"]').attr('href', 'green1.css');
        }`

Comment: You should only have one localStorage item if there's only one variable that you want to test for (color). If you could maybe link to a CodePen with what you're trying to do, I could help.